# Пропал файл указанный в gitignore в других ветках

Tags: git, gitignore

Добавил в gitignore

```
!/rootfolder/js
/rootfolder/js/*
!/rootfolder/js/some.sale
/rootfolder/js/some.sale/*
!/rootfolder/js/some.sale/some_sale.js
```

и запушил на рабочую ветку master

Теперь переходим в старую ветку созданную из мастера до этого коммита (git checkout oldbranch) далее если зайти через ftp то увидим что данный файл /rootfolder/js/some.sale/some_sale.js отсутствует. Если же создать новую ветку из этого мастера то в ftp покажет этот файл.
Как это исправить не могу понять.
Я так понимаю что у старых веток gitignore не содержит этих изменений, а этот файл был добавлен в репо, но т.к. в старых ветках gitignore есть такая еще запись выше `/rootfolder/*` то получается он игнорит из репо этот файл и не показывает на ftp . Я недавно начал пользоваться гитом. Буду рад помощи. Ветку обновить из мастера не имею возможности.

Comment: Извините если я неверно выражаюсь, просто пока не могу. Я просто объясняю факт ошибки. Ситуация такая. Есть главный репозиторий и мой локальный репозиторий. Я сделал в локальной ветке данные изменения в гитигноре и запушил. Далее слил этот коммит с веткой мастер основного репо и дальше во всех ветках локального репо такая проблема как в описании.

Comment: Сделал изменения в файлах в локальной ветке test. git add файлы
git commit
git push
Далее из мастер ветки основного git merge origin/test --squash git commit

Comment: если ты потерял локальные файлы, то:  //

git хранит уйму "лишней инфы" до момента когда ты сделаешь git gc (зачистишь репу от мусора) //

скорее всего тебе поможет git-fsck (может быть с ключом --unreachable), найди нужный коммит и сделай из него новую ветку или скопируй нужные данные.

Comment: кроме того, ты можешь сделать `git checkout репа/имя_ветки -- путь_к_файлу` скорее всего,  `git checkout коммитХэш -- путь_к_файлу` сработают точно так же - если тебе нужно выдрать файл из другого гит-объекта

Comment: Спасибо попробую